# difference between "for the first time" and "the first time around"?

Tags: difference

What is the difference between the following sentences?

> He has failed the exam **for the first time**.
>
> He has failed **the exam the first time around**.

Do those phrases have indentical meanings? If they do, than what is the point of using the word *around* in the second sentence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they do not mean the same thing. Not only does **around** make the second  sentence grammatical, but the use of **for** in the first sentence gives that sentence a different meaning.

> He has failed the exam **for** the first time.

He may have written the exam five times before. But *this* time, the sixth time, he has failed it. It is the *first* time that he has failed it.

> He has failed the exam the first time around.

This means that it's the first time he's written the exam—and that he's failed it.

The sentence construction is a bit odd, but it works if you think of somebody announcing the result immediately after the attempt—and just before he attempts it a second time.

---

Note the difference that **around** makes in variations of the sentence:

> ✔ He has failed the exam the first time around.
>   ✘ He has failed the exam the first time.
>
> ✔ He failed the exam the first time around.
>   ✔ He failed the exam the first time.

In the *has failed* version, the sentence becomes ungrammatical if you simply remove **around**. However, I can't really explain *why* this is the case.

The final version without **around** seems correct, but it is also awkward; I would add *he wrote it* to the end.

Comment: I am sorry I cannot get what the word "around" is there for.. Can it be omitted?

Comment: *He has failed the exam the first time.* is ungrammatical. So, no. It cannot be omitted from that specific sentence construction. Consider: ✔ He walked **around** the block. ✘ He walked the block. I believe that *around* in your specific sentence acts similarly to "the first time going through the process." (But that full replacement wouldn't be correct either—it's just what *around* means.)

Comment: I believe that, "the first time" is an adverbial phrase, therefore it is grammatically incorrect to omit the target of that adverb, which is "around" – see also, https://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/topic/first-time-round